# Delete the Session of a logged in user which is later deleted by the Admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js

In my Express API, when a user is still logged in and the admin deletes that particular user from the database, I want the session data of that user to be deleted so it can no longer have access (I'm using Connect-PG-Simple as the session store).

I have already implemented a logic in my DELETE method so that if the user itself deletes its own account, it gets logged out and the session will be deleted:

```
  // If the user is Admin, don't log out or delete session of the admin after user deletion
  if (req.user.role === "ADMIN") {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "User Deleted Successfully" });
  } else {
    // If the user is not Admin, log out the deleted user and delete its session and clear its cookie
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
        res.status(200).json({ message: "User Deleted Successfully" });
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that when the admin deletes the user and the user tries to access the data, my app gets this error on every request:

```
failed to deserialize user out of session
```

These are my login and serialize/deserialize logic:

**Serialize/Deserialize:**

```
  // Store user id in session
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // Fetch user data from session
  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
      // Fetching user data of the stored id from session
      const findUser = await db.query(selectUserById, [id]);
      const user = findUser.rows[0];
      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
  });
```

**Login:**

```
const login = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    // If no user is found
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
    // If user is found
    req.login(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: "Login Successful",
          user: {
            id: req.user.id,
            name: req.user.name,
            email: req.user.email,
          },
        });
      }
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

**Is there any way I can avoid that error and delete the session data of that specific user?**